# Lagrange Quadratic Polynomial

Tags: mathematical-physics, lagrange-interpolation

The Lagrange quadratic polynomial
$$p_2(x)=\ell_0(x)\textsf{f}_0(x)+\ell_1(x)\textsf{f}_1(x)+\ell_2(x)\textsf{f}_2(x)$$
So I wanted to prove that $p_2(x)$ can be written in the following form $$p_2(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$$ with $A,B,C$ arbitrary scalars.

I was trying to use the Lagrange interpolation method but it didn't work.

Any thoughts?
Thanks.

Comment: Just expand it all out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider an example as follows:

**Example:** Construct the quadratic Lagrange interpolating polynomial $p_2(x)$ that interpolates the points $~(1,2), (3,4), ~\text{and}~ (5,6)~$.

**Answer:**

$$P_2(x)=2~\frac{(x−3)(x−5)}{(1−3)(1−5)}+4~\frac{(x−1)(x−5)}{(3−1)(3−5)}+6~\frac{(x−1)(x−3)}{(5−1)(5−3)}$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{4}~(x−3)(x−5)−(x−1)(x−5)+\frac{3}{4}~(x−1)(x−3)$$
$$\qquad=\frac{1}{4}~(x^2-8x+15)−(x^2-6x+5)+\frac{3}{4}~(x^2-4x+3)$$
$$\qquad=0~\cdot~x^2+x+1$$

---

So, the quadratic Lagrange interpolating polynomial, $~p_2~$ through the points $~(x_0,y_0), ~(x_1,y_1), ~\text{and}~ (x_2,y_2)$ as the following function:
$$p_2(x)=\ell_0(x)\textsf{f}_0(x)+\ell_1(x)\textsf{f}_1(x)+\ell_2(x)\textsf{f}_2(x)$$
can be written in the following form $$p_2(x)=Ax^2+Bx+C$$where
 $$\ell_0(x)=\frac{(x−3)(x−5)}{(1−3)(1−5)}=\frac{1}{8}~(x−3)(x−5)$$
$$\ell_1(x)=\frac{(x−1)(x−5)}{(3−1)(3−5)}=-\frac{1}{4}~(x−1)(x−5)$$
$$\ell_2(x)=\frac{(x−1)(x−3)}{(5−1)(5−3)}=\frac{1}{8}~(x−1)(x−3)$$
 $$\textsf{f}_0(x)=y_0=2,\qquad \textsf{f}_1(x)=y_1=4,\qquad \textsf{f}_2(x)=y_2=6$$ and
$$A=0,\qquad B=1,\qquad C=1$$